# Questions about sources of Infrared Radiation

Tags: photon-emission, infrared-radiation

Very simple question but I came across a website discussing sources of infrared radiation and it used an example to illustrate which objects emit more infrared than others. It said 'a candle flame emits more infrared radiation than a cat'. Is this true? A candle flame is much hotter but the mass difference between a candle flame and a cat is huge so surely the cat emits more infrared in total? I found another website that said the amount of infrared radiation emitted by a human is comparable to a 120W incandescent light bulb - and they reach 2000+ degrees Celsius.

Thanks

Comment: Whatever the comparison it must be some total power rather than more IR. More IR means very little in this context.

Comment: Thanks. So which would emit more total power in infrared - a cat at room temperature or a candle flame?